# Nearest Neighbor on a 3d Grid

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, physics

In Solid State Physics we were analyzing a crystal with a simple cubic unit cell and wanted to compute the number of first nearest neighbors, second nearest neighbors and so on and their corresponding distances.

I can see this is related to the number of solutions of:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=r_n^2$$
with $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$ the number of steps in each direction and $r_n$ the distance of the $n$-nearest neighbor.

However, that time we used an approximation to solve this. I am wondering if there is a nice exact expression for this? or any known result?

Comment: Those are the coefficients of $\theta_3(z)^3$. Look up Jacobi's theta-function. $r_n^2$ can be any natural number not of the form $4^m(8k+7)$.

Comment: Related: http://oeis.org/A005875